# Oracle: Call stored procedure inside the package

Tags: oracle, package

I have the following package:

```
create or replace package PKG1
as
procedure INIT
(
  nRN                       in number,
  nREC_TYPE                 in number,
  nIDENT                    out number
);
```

I'm not sure how to call it from PL/SQL Developer environment. I've tried this:

```
DECLARE
  procId NUMBER;

BEGIN
  EXECUTE PKG1.INIT(1143824, 0, procId);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(procId);
END;
```

But, there's an ORA-06550 (PLS-00103) error.

As you can see I have 2 input and 1 output parameter. I want to print out output parameter. That's all.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You're nearly there, just take out the EXECUTE:

```
DECLARE
  procId NUMBER;

BEGIN
  PKG1.INIT(1143824, 0, procId);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(procId);
END;
```

Answer (score 8):

To those that are incline to use GUI:

Click <kbd>Right mouse</kbd> button on procecdure name then select `Test`

[image]

Then in new window you will see script generated just add the parameters and click on `Start Debugger` or <kbd>F9</kbd>

[image]

Hope this saves you some time.