# TypeORM getting value of DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE() from STORED PROCEDURE within PACKAGE

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, nestjs, typeorm

I was able to call the stored procedure from a package, which is also explained in the following ***[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026016/oracle-call-stored-procedure-inside-the-package).***

My problem is I wasn't able to take the result from `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TOTAL)` where `TOTAL` is the variable I want to take with *type* **NUMBER**. Since the procedure only processing and wasn't returning value as raw output (like from select), I keep getting undefined as the result.

I've also read the following ***[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39140672/getting-a-value-from-stored-procedure-within-a-stored-procedure)*** but I still unable to get the `TOTAL`.

My question is:

- Is it possible to get the `TOTAL` value from `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TOTAL)` to be passed on TypeORM after executing the query?
- And if it's not possible how to process or execute the procedure to be able to get `TOTAL` in `return` expression on a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344880/execute-stored-procedure-from-a-function) (It was said that it is not good) / another stored procedure?

---

For reference, I was using one of the following queries at the moment to be able to get the result from stored procedure `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`:

First one:

```
BEGIN pkg_one.endpkg(:id, :adeius,:status,:aregate,:mapony, :total); END;
```

Second one:

```
DECLARE 
    ID NUMBER; 
    ADEIUS NUMBER; 
    STATUS NUMBER; 
    AREGATE VARCHAR2(200); 
    MAPONY NUMBER; 
    TOTAL NUMBER; 
BEGIN 
    ID := :ID; 
    ADEIUS := :ADEIUS; 
    STATUS := :STATUS; 
    AREGATE := :AREGATE; 
    MAPONY := :MAPONY; 
    PKG_ONE.ENDPKG(
        ID => ID, 
        ADEIUS => ADEIUS, 
        STATUS => STATUS, 
        AREGATE => AREGATE, 
        MAPONY => MAPONY, 
        TOTAL => TOTAL); 
    TOTAL := TOTAL; 
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TOTAL); --either the initial procedure or the call TOTAL is the Result I want
END;
```

---

Updated working function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PTD (ID IN NUMBER,ADIEUS IN NUMBER ,STATUS IN NUMBER,AREGATE IN VARCHAR2,MAPONY IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS TOTAL NUMBER;
BEGIN 
PKG_ONE.ENDPKG(ID, ADIEUS,STATUS,AREGATE,MAPONY, TOTAL);
  RETURN TOTAL;
END PTD;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` doesn't *return* anything, you can't "take the result from it" (as you said). It just displays a string (procedure's parameter) to the screen, if you enable it (`SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`). So, if `PKG_ONE.ENDPKG` is a procedure whose `OUT` parameter is `TOTAL`, then you'll have it and do whatever you want with it. If that procedure doesn't return `TOTAL`, it'll be `NULL`. `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` doesn't have to do anything with it.

Comment: I don't know TypeORM but I doubt it fetches and prints the DBMS_OUTPUT buffer automatically. Possibly you could write something to call `dbms_output.get_lines` and fetch the result into a local array and loop through that. DBMS_OUTPUT is just a crude debugging tool anyway so I'm not sure why you would need to use it in your web interface.

Comment: It was returning something on `DBMS_Output` tab in TOAD, where as in SQL Dev it wasn't as obvious which is in `Output Variables` tab. Problem is not that I can't see the result, but I can't pass it to my backend. I've tried searching on TypeORM github but it was said, it's currently unsupported at the moment it was written. Also `TOTAL` and the SP was doing fine.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Yeah, it doesn't since it was mapping Object related. I also doesn't need the `get_lines` for web interface actually. But I want to pass the value. I will try again using `get_lines` and see how it goes.

Comment: You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830370/getting-output-from-dbms-output-get-lines-using-jdbc) relevant...

Comment: @Littlefoot For more clarification, the `PKG_ONE.ENDPKG` has`OUT` parameter which is `TOTAL`. 
@MarmiteBomber thanks. I was still struggling to make the `get_lines` work. Hitting the `Error(1,31): PLS-00103`: Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following:     <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    current delete exists prior.

Comment: Identifier names must start with a letter.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Yeah, also I need to define the `IN/OUT` and the datatype. I've compiled the function successfully but to be honest, I don't know whether using a function to call SP is considered bad practice or horrible as stated in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344880/execute-stored-procedure-from-a-function). I will test with TypeORM after this.

Comment: [Edit: posted this before I saw your last comment above.] Your function shouldn't call `dbms_output.get_lines`. The function would put lines into the buffer, and your calling framework would get them following any database call, which is what Toad and SQL Developer etc do. But as I mentioned, it's a basic diagnostic tool and not an output stream.

Comment: Taking a step back, if the aim is to get a value back from a PL/SQL procedure or function so you can use it in your web app, then I think you should focus on how to do that in NestJS/TypeORM. Probably there is some syntax for mapping database call parameters to local variables. Forget all about `dbms_output`, it's not the right tool for this.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Yeah that's the way to go, as @littlefoot said earlier "`DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` doesn't have to do anything with it." At the moment, I was able to manipulate the output from SP to TypeORM variable already. I've tried to compose an answer earlier based on the progress I have since I was able to kind of `SELECT` from the function which I created earlier as I've updated in the OP above. Thanks for the help. If you got any feedback it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the original question:

- Is it possible to get the TOTAL value from
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TOTAL) to be passed on TypeORM after executing
  the query?

It might be possible as stated in one of the comments [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830370/getting-output-from-dbms-output-get-lines-using-jdbc) by [@Marmite Bomber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4808122/marmite-bomber). But it's unnecessary to use `DBMS_OUTPUT` for passing the value.

- And if it's not possible how to process or execute the procedure to
  be able to get TOTAL in return expression on a function (It was said
  that it is not good) / another stored procedure?

Below is the working function, SQL and TypeORM query after `SELECT`ing the `function` from Stored Procedure (SP) which are updated earlier:

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PTD (ID IN NUMBER,ADIEUS IN NUMBER ,STATUS IN NUMBER,AREGATE IN VARCHAR2,MAPONY IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS TOTAL NUMBER;
BEGIN 
PKG_ONE.ENDPKG(ID, ADIEUS,STATUS,AREGATE,MAPONY, TOTAL);
  RETURN TOTAL;
END PTD;
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT PTD(:ID, :ADIEUS,:STATUS,:AREGATE,:MAPONY) AS VAL FROM DUAL; -- NOTE that :var is input
```

TypeORM:

```
await getManager().query("SELECT PTD(" + id + ", " + adeius+ ", " + status + ", '" + aregate + "', " + mapony + ") AS VAL FROM DUAL")
   .then(
      res => {
          data.count = res[0].VAL; //note that data.count is from const data = { count:0 };
      },
   );
```

***Note: It might be considered [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344880/execute-stored-procedure-from-a-function) to use a function to call SP. And previously [it's not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896445/why-can-we-not-execute-a-stored-procedure-inside-a-function-in-sql-server).***

Personally it's debatable whether it's bad practice or not, but so long as either the function which call SP or the SP didn't affect any [database state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#limitations-and-restrictions). It's should be okay.

Comment: It seemed like the linked discussion about calling procedures within functions in SQL Server was referring to some technical restriction, but I didn't understand it. It's absolutely fine in Oracle, especially for functions that you don't call from SQL.

Comment: Does TypeORM not support bind variables? It seems a bit resource-intensive to build a new SQL statement out of literals for every single call, and it won't scale. (For one thing, Oracle tries to cache its SQL statements, and a SQL generator producing thousands of separate queries would wreck that cache.)

Comment: AFAIK, TypeORM doesn't support PL/SQL as it does to CRUD since it was stated on [2nd issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2161#issuecomment-390144805) that I found that TypeORM is only about Object Relational Mapping. From my searching I also found 3 issues which are SP related: [1](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1207), [2](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2161), [3](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/465). Which aren't that helpful to me when trying to get a value from SP as select does on querybuilder.